Moving through pages using PHP
Suppose I reach page 'B' clicking a button in page 'A', then reach page 'C' starting from page 'B' etc..
because I know path, in page B  I can put <a href="/pathBackToPageA">Go Back </a> to go back form B to A and so on and after I could return page A going back from C to B and the to A.
Suppose now you want reach page B starting from page D obviously you would return to D going back from C to B and from B to D, but in page B the 'Go Back' button is pointing  A. So which is the way, if you want have only a button to go back the right page?
I was trying this class:
class ReturnHereVM
{
    protected string $base='/';
    protected string $backWardPage='';
    protected string $forWardPage='';
    protected string $curPage='';
    protected string $curController='';

    public function __construct(
        ?string $curController='',
    ){
        $this->curController=$curController;
    }

    public function getBackWardPage()
    { 
        return $this->backWardPage;
    }
    public function getCurPage(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['returnHere']['curPage'])){
            $this->curPage= $_SESSION['returnHere']['curPage'];
        }
        return $this->curPage;
    }
    public function getForWardPage()
    {
        return $this->forWardPage;
    }
    public function getCurController()
    {
        return $this->curController;
    }
    public function setCurController($val){
        $this->curController=$val;
    }
    public function setBackWard($val){
        $_SESSION['returnHere']['backWard'] = $val;
        $this->backWardPage=$val;
    }
    public function setCurPage($val){
        $_SESSION['returnHere']['curPage']=$val;
        $this->curPage=$val;
    }
    public function setForWard($val)
    {
        $_SESSION['returnHere']['forWard'] = $val;
        $this->forWardPage=$val;
    }
    public function setBacPages(){

    }
    public function setPages(string $start,string $val,string $fval){
        if($start=='i'){
            unset($_SESSION['returnHere']);
            $this->setBackWard($this->base);
        }else{
            $this->setBackWard($start);
        }
        $this->setCurPage($val);
        $this->setForWard($fval);

}

but it goes fine only if I go from page A to B and return directly to A from B.
Steps I performed are:
($this->contrName is controller Name of the page;
$this->pagination is the object class of the paginator;)
in page A
        //because page A is the first, previous is Index = 'i'
        $thisPage= '/' . $this->contrName . '/list/pag&' . $this->pagination->getPage();
        $nextPage='/'.$this->contrName.'/detail/';//this is to reach page B
        $this->returnHere->setPages('i',$thisPage,$nextPage);

in page B
        $prevPage=  $this->returnHere->getCurPage();
        $thisPage= '/' . $this->contrName . '/detail/' . $id;
        $nextPage= '/' . $this->contrName . '/edit/'.$id;//this is to reach page C
        $this->returnHere->setPages($prevPage, $thisPage, $nextPage);

in page C
        $prevPage =  $this->returnHere->getCurPage();
        $thisPage = '/' . $this->contrName . '/edit/' . $id;
        $nextPage = '';//this is last page of the series
        $this->returnHere->setPages($prevPage, $thisPage, $nextPage);

but if I should return from C to B I never could return A!
because this isn't right way I didn't try from page D

Instead of using "Back" ($prevPage) --- Why not just build and use a navigation bar (say at the top of the page) with all the hyperlinks of the pages ?

"Back" and "Forward" buttons are built into every browser; you don't need to reinvent those. "Next" and "Previous" links are only useful when the application is not using the order you've navigated, e.g. "previous page" on page 42 of stone results should always point to page 41, regardless of how the user reached page 42.

Why don't you use JS to get back in the previous page?

do you know what are breadcrumbs navigation

surely there are better ways to achieve the same result
take a look at this, the explanations are in the comments
<?php
//maybe this is optional if you have already started the session on every page
//you can remove this=========================================================
//============================================================================
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) session_start();
//============================================================================
class ReturnHereVM
{
    protected string $base='/';
    protected string $backWardPage='';
    protected string $forWardPage='';
    protected string $curPage='';
    protected string $curController='';

    public function __construct(
        ?string $curController='',
    ){
        $this->curController=$curController;
    }

    public function getBackWardPage()
    { 
        return $this->backWardPage;
    }
    public function getCurPage(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['returnHere']['curPage'])){
            $this->curPage= $_SESSION['returnHere']['curPage'];
        }
        return $this->curPage;
    }
    
    public function getForWardPage()
    {
        return $this->forWardPage;
    }
    public function getCurController()
    {
        return $this->curController;
    }
    public function setCurController($val){
        $this->curController=$val;
    }
    public function setBackWard($val){
        $_SESSION['returnHere']['backWard'] = $val;
        $this->backWardPage=$val;
    }
    public function setCurPage($val){
        $_SESSION['returnHere']['curPage']=$val;
        $this->curPage=$val;
    }
    public function setForWard($val)
    {
        $_SESSION['returnHere']['forWard'] = $val;
        $this->forWardPage=$val;
    }

    //maybe some of my code could be placed here inside
    //and maybe you could rename this "setBackPages" ^_^
    public function setBacPages(){

    }
    public function setPages(string $start,string $val,string $fval){
        $backward=$this->base;
        if($start=='i'){
            //unset($_SESSION['returnHere']);
            //some minor edit for make new code and old code compatible
            $_SESSION['returnHere']=[];
        }else if($start==''){
            $backward=$this->getCurPage();
        }else{
            $backward=$start;
        }
        $this->setBackWard($backward);

        //here start the fix part
        //you need to map your route based on the current page
        //=======================================================================

        //this is just for initialize the array
        if(!isset($_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards'])){
            $_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards']=[];
        }
        

        //here i map the backward url based on current page value
        //actually base64 is optional but i don't like use urls as array keys
        //NOTE: #############################################################
        //different get parameter are going to create a different maps####### 
        //###################################################################
        if(!isset($_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards'][base64_encode($val)]))
            $_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards'][base64_encode($val)]=$backward;

        //=======================================================================
        
        $this->setCurPage($val);
        $this->setForWard($fval);
    }
    // this just return  the prev page mapped in setPages or $this->base if no map is found 
    public function getPrevPage($curPage=''){
        $prev=$this->base;
        if(
            isset($_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards']) &&
            isset($_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards'][base64_encode($curPage)]) &&
            1 //pleas ignore this ... is my way to indent if/and... just ignore it
        ){
            $prev=$_SESSION['returnHere']['backwards'][base64_encode($curPage)];
        }    
        return $prev;
    }//this were missing in your code i suppose just because of a bad copy and paste
}

?>

for your Pages:
//PAGE B:

$thisPage= '/' . $this->contrName . '/detail/' . $id;
$nextPage= '/' . $this->contrName . '/edit/'.$id;//this is to reach page C
//here the order of the following code is important so don't chenge line order
//===========================================================================
$prevPage=  '';
$this->returnHere->setPages($prevPage, $thisPage, $nextPage);
$prevPage=$this->returnHere->getPrevPage($thisPage);
//===========================================================================


//PAGE C:

$thisPage = '/' . $this->contrName . '/edit/' . $id;
$nextPage = '';//this is last page of the series
//here the order of the following code is important so don't chenge line order
//===========================================================================
$prevPage=  '';
$this->returnHere->setPages($prevPage, $thisPage, $nextPage);
$prevPage=$this->returnHere->getPrevPage($thisPage);
//===========================================================================

Edit : this are my tests:
page_a.php:
<?php
include_once("./ReturnHereVM.php");

//because page A is the first, previous is Index = 'i'
$returnHere = new ReturnHereVM();
$thisPage= './page_a.php';
$nextPage='./page_b.php';
$returnHere->setPages('i',$thisPage,$nextPage);

?>

<a href="<?php echo $prevPage; ?>" />prev</a>
<br><br>
<a href="<?php echo $nextPage; ?>" />next</a>

page_b.php
    <?php

include_once("./ReturnHereVM.php");


$returnHere = new ReturnHereVM();
$thisPage= './page_b.php';
$nextPage='./page_c.php';
$prevPage='';
$returnHere->setPages($prevPage,$thisPage,$nextPage);
$prevPage=$returnHere->getPrevPage($thisPage);

?>

<a href="<?php echo $prevPage; ?>" />prev</a>
<br><br>
<a href="<?php echo $nextPage; ?>" />next</a>

page_c.php
<?php

include_once("./ReturnHereVM.php");

$returnHere = new ReturnHereVM();
$thisPage= './page_c.php';
$nextPage='./page_c.php';
$prevPage='';
$returnHere->setPages($prevPage,$thisPage,$nextPage);
$prevPage=$returnHere->getPrevPage($thisPage);

?>

<a href="<?php echo $prevPage; ?>" />prev</a>
<br><br>
<a href="<?php echo $nextPage; ?>" />next</a>

